# VB6 - Are disabled controls only disabled for user input or for code too?

Tags: forms, vb6, controls, disabled-control

Maybe a stupid question, but when a control on a VB6 form is disabled can the code still change that code's value? In other words, is it only disabled for the users, or is it disabled for the code too?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK, I admit I was being lazy. I tried it, and yes, even when a control is disabled VB6 can change its value at runtime.